# Unable to pass Id from listbox items in mvc 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, listbox, asp.net-ajax

I've coded for multiple values that resides inside listbox on button click. I have used autocomplete textbox to get the required value along with its id. Then i managed to add those values inside the listbox. Now what i want is to pass id's against those values in listbox instead of names. Below is my code that I'm running.

**StudentBatch.cs**

```
 public string studentId { get; set; }
        public string StudentName { get; set; }
   public List<string> selectedids { get; set; }
        public List<string> names { get; set; }
        public List<string> SelectedNames { get; set; }
```

**Create.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Student", FormMethod.Post))
{
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StudentName, new { id = "StudentName" })
        <input type="button" value="Add Text" id="addtypevalue" />
        <div id="typevaluelist"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="new" style="display:none;">
    <div class="typevalue">
        <input type="text" name="typevalue" />
        <button type="button" class="delete">Delete</button>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="hiddensq">
</div>

    for (int i = 0; i < Model.names.Count; i++)
    {
        @Html.Hidden("UserValues", Model.names[i]);
    }

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedNames, new SelectList(Model.names))


<div id="partialDiv">
    @{
        Html.RenderPartial("GetListBox", Model);
    }

</div>


<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
        }




<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#StudentName").autocomplete({
            //autocomplete: {
            //    delay: 0,
            //    minLength: 1,
            source: function (request, response)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Student/CreateStudent",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function(data) {
                        try {
                            response($.map(data,
                                function (item)
                                {
                                    return { label: item.FirstName, id: item.Id };
                                }));
                        } catch (err) {
                        }
                    }
                });
            },
            messages:
                {
                noResults: "jhh", results: "jhjh"
            }

        });

    });
</script>





<script>

    $(function () {
        $('#addtypevalue').click(function (e) {

            var name = $("#StudentName").val();
            alert(name);
            $('#SelectedNames').
                append($("<option></option>").
                attr("value", name).
                text(name));

            $('#hiddensq').append("<input name='UserValues' type='hidden' value='"+ name +"'/>");
        });
    });
</script>
```

**StudentController.cs**

```
 public ActionResult Create()
        {
            Context.Student student = new Context.Student();
            Models.StudentBatch studBatch = new Models.StudentBatch();
            studBatch.names = new List<string>();
            studBatch.names.Add("Add Student Names");
            studBatch.BatchNumberList = student.getBatchList();
            return View(studBatch);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateStudent(string Prefix)
        {
            CreateUser user = new CreateUser();
            string stdid = "f14570f0-e7a1-4c22-bf69-60ffbeb7e432";
            var StudentList1 = user.GetAllUsers().ToList().Where(u => u.FirstName.Contains(Prefix) && u.usertypeid == stdid);
            var StudentList = user.GetAllUsers().ToList();

            var searchlist = (from student in StudentList1
                              where student.FirstName.Contains(Prefix)
                              select student).ToList();


            return Json(StudentList1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }


        // POST: Student/Create
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Models.StudentBatch student, IEnumerable<string> UserValues)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The selected options will be send to the server when the form is submitted. That means, user has to select an item in the list box. If you want to send the Id. Set the id as the options's value attribute value. If you want , you can select one ore more value in the list box. Ex : `$('#SelectedNames').val(["Aaa","Bbb"]);`

Comment: So if i write $('#SelectedNames').val(["Id","FirstName"]); it returns [object object] in the listbox.

Comment: No no!. If you want to select the item "Aaa" and "Bbb" (multiple options), use the `val` method to do so.

Comment: Multiple items are already being selected from listbox. What i'm trying to say is, the names to be displayed in the listbox and their required id's is to be passed in the controller post action method. So in case if i write 
"return { label: item.Id, id: item.Id };" this is how I'm getting the id, but i dont want to display it. So how do i access all the ids from the listbox.

Comment: You need to set the id as the option's value attribute value and when the form is submitted, the selected options ids will be submitted.

Comment: Can you please provide any short example if possible, or can suggest modification in the code.

Comment: Currently you are setting the name as the `value` of the option (`attr("value", name).`). You need to set the Id there  instead of name

Comment: thats the main issue to set the id there. And if i set the id there, wouldn't the id display inside listbox instead of name?

Comment: Why are you using a ListBox? And as I stated in your previous question, you use the `.select` event of autocomplete, NOT the `.click()` event of the textbox

Comment: Using listbox to collect values from autocomplete textbox with their id's.

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks for your help. Is there any similar way i can remove items from listbox?

Comment: Do not use a ListBox. Just create hidden inputs in the `.select` event handler (and add the text in a `<div>` or similar so that the user knows what they have added)

Comment: Well I'm using listbox in case if i have to remove any selected item. That's what I'm going through with now, that the user can remove the value from the listbox and the id should automatically be removed also. Any suggestions on it?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly the problem here is passing multiple IDs from a listbox to a POST? One possible way is to assign viewbag like thus in your controller:

```
ViewBag.StudentList = new SelectList(db.StudentBatch, "studentId", "StudentName");
```

I use entities to access my models, I think you have a little bit different approach but the point is to give a collection to the Selectlist. Then you specify the data value field and the data text field.

Then in your view, note that it's not ListBoxFor, as it's dynamic:

```
@Html.ListBox("StudentList", null)
```

Then finally to be able to receive the values in the POST add the following parameter to your action and you should be able to iterate through it:

```
string[] StudentList
```

Comment: Its not that what you've explained. The autocomplete textbox values are stored in listbox on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Finally managed to get the related from the listbox. I followed the instruction mentioned in a particular question. That's how i did.

```
 $("#StudentName").autocomplete({
    source: function (request, response) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            // async: false, NEVER do this
            url: '@Url.Action("CreateStudent", "Student")', // don't hard code your url's
            data: { Prefix: request.term }, // change
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            // contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", delete
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        id: item.id
                    }
                }));
            }
        })
    },select: function(event, ui) {
        $.ajax({
            cache: false,
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDetails", "Student")',
            data: { id: ui.item.id },
            success: function (data) {
                var name = $("#StudentName").val();
                $('#SelectedNames').
               append($("<option></option>").
               attr("value", ui.item.id).
               text(name));
                $('#hiddensq').append("<input name='UserValues' type='hidden' value='" + ui.item.id + "'/>");

            }
        });
    }
});
</script>
```

**and in the controller class**

```
[HttpPost]


   public JsonResult GetDetails(string id)
    {

        ViewBag.Value = id;

        return Json(ViewBag.Value, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```